# Why promise are slower in rendering than observable even Observables are lazy whereas promises are not

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, observable

Like promises, Observables also follow the push model. However observable are lazy as they need some subscriber to get the data.

```
let Rx = require('rxjs');
let isTrue = true;

let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (isTrue) {
        resolve('Hi Promise')
    } else {
        reject(new Error('Message error in promise'))
    }
})

let data$ = new Rx.Observable((observer) => {
    if (isTrue) {
        observer.next('Hi Observable');
    } else {
        observer.error(new Error('error observer'))
    }
})


// DATA Collector

console.log(promise, data$)
//Promise { 'Hi Promise' } Observable { _isScalar: false, _subscribe: [Function] }

promise.then((data) => {
    console.log(data).   //Hi Promise
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
})

data$.subscribe((data) => {
    console.log(data);    // output - ‘Hi Observable’
});
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Promise { 'Hi Promise' } Observable { _isScalar: false, _subscribe: [Function] }
Hi Observable
Hi Promise
```

In the case of promises, they execute immediately and the data is available. However data is not available in observable unless they are subscribed.

**Still the Observable part is printed first and promise part later?**

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in [docs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable):

> Subscribing to an Observable is analogous to calling a Function.
> Some people claim that Observables are asynchronous. That is not true.

So you need to deliver your messages in async style:

```js
        setTimeout(() => {
            observer.next('Hi Observable');
        })
```

Otherwise, all the messages will be sync.

Moreover, this is the same behaviour as the standard [`EventEmitter`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_asynchronous_vs_synchronous)